# How to migrate from MySQL to Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, galera

I have a MySQL database with some data in it. Now I want to create cluster from this this database.

I've already configured Galera, and I have just this single node. Now, how to replicate the data to ather nodes?

Will it happen auto-maicaly by Galera, or should I dump current data first, then clean the DB on the first node, start all other nodes and load the data to one of them and wait for them to replicate.

Following question is: how to add/remove nodes in runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just if somebody is still interested in an answer to this.

The procedure is:

- bootstrap the cluster by starting the first node
- add other nodes as needed

Any new nodes will first receive the current state of the DB before becoming available.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/getting-started-with-mariadb-galera-cluster/#getting-started